# Decrease Bootstrap Navigation Breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap and the Navbar collapses into responsive view at 1320px.

How can I adjust this so that the navbar only collapses into responsive view below 1280px? All the questions I've seen on SO have been to increase the breakpoint, where I would like to reduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion, the below code is what was needed in order to decrease the break point and keep the desktop version of the navigation bar.

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 1170px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        width: auto;
        border-top: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: block !important;
        height: auto !important;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
    }   
    .navbar-nav > li,
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
    #navbar-settings {
        float: right;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding: 12px 36px;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
        margin-top: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        float: left;
        min-width: 160px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin: 2px 0 0;
        text-align: left;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
    }
    .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
        color: #626366 !important;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a specific media query for that,

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   .collapse {
       display: none !important;
   }
}
```

I will update this answer for you if you post your code.